# Add datetime to datetime

Tags: vb.net

My birth year- 1975
Month- 08
Day- 28
Hour- 19
Minute- 10
Second- 22

I want to add 1.746387366 year to my(birth year, month, day, hour, minute, second) to get a new year month day hour minute second

How can I

Thanks.

Comment: You don't add two datetimes, instead you add a datetime to a timespan object. Your birth date being the datetime and the 1.74 years being a timespan.

Answer (score 0):

You create a datetime of your birth moment:

```
Dim birthdate = new DateTime(1975, 8, 28, 19, 10, 22)
```

And you add that number of years to it:

```
Dim result = birthdate.AddYears(1.746387366)
```